# Porque minha ListView está mostrando uma linha apenas?

Tags: android, listview

Eu tenho uma ListView porém só uma linha está aparecendo, sendo que estou cadastrando 5 dados (item 1, item 2...)
Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo e o que eu posso fazer?

**Activity.java**

```
public class HomeOrcamentoActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lv1;

private String lv_arr[] = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_orcamento);

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            switch( position )
            {
                case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(HomeOrcamentoActivity.this, HomeReformasEReparosActivity.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                    break;
                case 1:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(HomeOrcamentoActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="#F3F3F3">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema reside no fato de o seu `RelativeLayout` estar com uma altura definida para `48dp`

Altere a linha:

```
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

para:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Obrigado, Ramaral. Funcionou!